# Number of figure by chapter

Tags: numbering

I need number of figure by chapter:

I'm using this but sometimes it repeats the numeration

```
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin{figure}{chapter}
\counterwithin{table}{chapter}
```

example:

```
chapter1
  figure 1.1
  figure 1.2
  figure 1.3
chapter2
  figure 2.1
 section 2.1
  figure 2.2
  figure 2.3
chapter3
  figure 3.1
  figure 3.2
 section 3.1
  figure 3.3
```

example:

```
     \documentclass{report}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin{figure}{section}

\begin{document}
\chapter{}
\section{section 1.1}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\rule{1cm}{1cm}% placeholder for graphic
\caption{A figure}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\rule{1cm}{1cm}% placeholder for graphic
\caption{A figure}
\end{figure}

\section{section 1.2}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\rule{1cm}{1cm}% placeholder for graphic
\caption{A figure}
\end{figure}



\chapter{}
\section{section 2.1}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\rule{1cm}{1cm}% placeholder for graphic
\caption{A figure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

this is the screeshot:
[image]

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) of which replicates your problem.

Comment: Plus from your example it is not obvious that any counter gets repeated. According to what I see, each *figure* counter is unique, and so is each *section* counter.

Comment: If you want chapters why not use report class? Then all you're expecting will be fixed...

Comment: @santimirandarp I am new to latex, please help me

Comment: @santimirandarp i edited my question, it still does not work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Use `report` class when chapters are needed.
- Remove some packages (not needed to get the output).
- Do not include numbers in section and chapters (those are created automatically by latex)

  ```
  \documentclass{report}

  \usepackage{float}

  \begin{document}

  \chapter{ } %if you want a name write it as \chapter{name}



  \begin{figure}[H]
  \centering
      \rule{1cm}{1cm}% placeholder for graphic
  \caption{A figure}
  \end{figure}

  \section{}

  \begin{figure}[H]
  \centering
  \rule{1cm}{1cm}% placeholder for graphic
   \caption{A figure}
  \end{figure}

  \section{ }

  \begin{figure}[H]
  \centering
  \rule{1cm}{1cm}% placeholder for graphic
  \caption{A figure}
  \end{figure}

   \end{document}
  ```

Comment: yes, this result is good, what is the secret?

Comment: Glad to know it. @x-rw remove `\usepackage{chngcntr}`
`\counterwithin{figure}{section}` and modify the argument of `\section{}`. Also, use reportclass when you need chapters.

Comment: muchas gracias, su respuesta me ayudo a aprender algo nuevo (la clase report), i am user with language native spanish